# Extract EXIF data from an image blob (binary string) in PHP

Tags: php, image-manipulation, exif

The PHP function `exif_read_data()` requires a filename for input, however I only have the image data in a string (such that I can use `imagecreatefromstring()`) and I can not write it to a temp file. How do I extract EXIF information without writing this image string to disk? All I really want is the Orientation attribute. This is on a Linux system if it matters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A stream wrapper can turn your string/image into something useable as a filehandle, as shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php). However, I can't see any way of turning that filehandle into something that can masquerade as the filename that exif_read_data expects.

You might try passing the `data://` pseudo-url listed on that page and see if the exif function will accept it.

Comment: wow, that did the trick! thanks so much!  here's what I used: 

`exif_read_data("data://image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($imageString))`

Answer (score 9):

Adding [@rymo’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465665/extract-exif-data-from-an-image-blob-binary-string-in-php#comment6195861_5465741) on [@MarcB’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465741/117259) as a separate answer:

This works:

```
$exif = exif_read_data("data://image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($image));
echo $exif['Orientation'];
```